# Pyspark dataframe : remove cumulative pairs from pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to remove pairs with the same id, keeping only one of them in the data frame.

Also I can't drop duplicates by 'id' as it's possible that I have multiple combination for same "id" which might not be cumulative pairs example:
I tried in python as below but not sure how to it in pyspark, any help is appreciated.

```
m_f_1['value'] = m_f_1.apply(lambda x: str(x['value_x']) + str(x['value_y']) if x['value_x'] > x['value_y'] else str(x['value_y']) + str(x['value_x']), axis =1)
```

Input dataframe m_f_1 is :

```
  id     value.x       value.y 
 100057    38953993985    38993095846 
 100057    38993095845    38953993985  
 100057    38993095845    38993095846
 100057    38993095846    38953993985
 100011    38989281716    38996868028   
 100011    38996868028    38989281716  
 100019    38916115350    38994231881  
 100019    38994231881    38916115350
```

Output should be

> head(res)

```
  id      value.x      value.y 
 100011    38989281716 38996868028 
 100019    38916115350 38994231881  
 100031    38911588267 38993358322 
 100057    38953993985 38993095846 
 100057    38993095845 38953993985  
 100057    38993095845 38993095846
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pyspark.sql.functions` to achieve it. `pyspark.sql.functions.greatest` and `pyspark.sql.functions.least` take the maximum and minimum respectively. `pyspark.sql.functions.concat` is used to connect strings.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

sqlContext = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
data = [(100057,38953993985,38993095846)
    , (100057,38993095845,38953993985)
    , (100057,38993095845,38993095846)
    , (100057,38993095846,38953993985)
    , (100011,38989281716,38996868028)
    , (100011,38996868028,38989281716)
    , (100019,38916115350,38994231881)
    , (100019,38994231881,38916115350)]
m_f_1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema=['id','value_x','value_y'])

m_f_1 = m_f_1.withColumn('value', F.concat(F.greatest('value_x','value_y').cast('string')
                                           ,F.least('value_x','value_y').cast('string')))
m_f_1 = m_f_1.dropDuplicates(subset=['value']).drop('value').sort('id')
m_f_1.show(truncate=False)

+------+-----------+-----------+
|id    |value_x    |value_y    |
+------+-----------+-----------+
|100011|38989281716|38996868028|
|100019|38916115350|38994231881|
|100057|38993095845|38953993985|
|100057|38953993985|38993095846|
|100057|38993095845|38993095846|
+------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work even if you want to get unique from more than 2 columns.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(100057,38953993985,38993095846),(100057,38993095845,38953993985),(100057,38993095845,38993095846),(100057,38993095846,38953993985),(100011,38989281716,38996868028),(100011,38996868028,38989281716),(100019,38916115350,38994231881),(100019,38994231881,38916115350)],['id','value_x','value_y'])


from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

def list_sort(x,y):
  return sorted([x,y])

udf_list_sort = udf(list_sort, ArrayType(IntegerType()))

spark.udf.register("udf_list_sort",udf_list_sort)

df1 = df.selectExpr("id","udf_list_sort(value_x,value_y) as value_x_y").distinct()


df1.selectExpr("id AS id",
              "value_x_y[0] AS value_x",
              "value_x_y[1] AS value_y").show()

#+------+---------+---------+
#|    id|  value_x|  value_y|
#+------+---------+---------+
#|100019|261409686|339526217|
#|100011|334576052|342162364|
#|100057|299288321|338390182|
#|100057|299288321|338390181|
#|100057|338390181|338390182|
#+------+---------+---------+
```